# python opencv3.0.0-beta 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
fgbg1 = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()'
```

*Enviroment:*

- x64 win7
- win32 python 2.7.3
- opencv 3.0.0-beta

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested in [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#createbackgroundsubtractormog2), which, although not documented, has a python binding in opencv 3.0.0-beta.

```
import cv2
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

both were moved in 3.0 to the [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib)

you will need to build it along with your main opencv repo using cmake. (no prebuild versions of this available) then running the INSTALL project (or make install) will copy your new cv2.pyd to the python folder.

then:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG # note additional bgsegm namespace !
<built-in function createBackgroundSubtractorMOG>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()`
because `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2` was replaced in the latest versions of **opencv**.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following solutions:

```
cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

or:

```
cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```